# Python - run/execute IF statement only once inside loop

Tags: python, function, loops, if-statement, global-variables

How can I execute/run IF statement inside another IF only once?
I am reading file, line by line I would like to execute commands inside IF statement only once.

I had tried global variables, define and call Function, but no luck.

Could you please help me?

**Example:**

```
  i = 0 
  for x in enumerate(FILE, 1):
    i += 1
    
    if re.findall("*test1*", line):
      
      command1
      command2
      command3
      
      executed = True; (...and do not run commands again when the IF statement is fullfiled with another line from FILE)
```

Comment: You'll need to check `and not executed` somewhere…?! Or `break` the entire loop…?

Comment: Are you sure you want to continue evaluating the loop after the `if` is executed once? If not, just put `break` as the last statement in the `if` block.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a iteration requirement to the if statement like so:

```
i = 0 
j=0
for x in enumerate(FILE, 1):
    i += 1
    
    if j == 0 and re.findall("*test1*", line):
        j+=1
        command1
        command2
        command3
```

This means it will only work on the first execution.

You could instead use the "executed" variable if you would like:

```
i = 0 
executed = False
for x in enumerate(FILE, 1):
    i += 1
    
    if executed == False and re.findall("*test1*", line):
        command1
        command2
        command3
        executed = True
```

Lastly, if you want to exit the loop entirely after the first execution you can use `break` like so:

```
i = 0 
for x in enumerate(FILE, 1):
    i += 1
    
    if re.findall("*test1*", line):
        command1
        command2
        command3
        break
```

Depends if you need to continue the loop or not.

Comment: That will not work if the `executed` check is after the `findall()`.  `findall` will still be run if executed is True.

Comment: @vinalti He said for the commands not to be run again. It is my understanding that the `if` statement can be evaluated as long as it is not `True`. Regardless, I edited it in case it matters.

Comment: Yes, but what's the use of running the regex (which is a really consuming operation) if you already know, with a boolean, if you will enter the loop or not.

Comment: I have figured it out, thanks to adding: executed = True/False............

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is to test `not executed` before to run the test, then if `executed` is `true`, the regex will not be run.
Example :

```py
  executed = False
  i = 0 
  for x in enumerate(FILE, 1):
    i += 1
    
    if ((not executed) and re.findall("*test1*", line)):
      # ... commands
      executed = True; 
      #don't run commands again when the IF statement sees executed is True
```

Another option would be to just skip the rest of the lines if you just want to ignore them. Example :

```py
  i = 0 
  for x in enumerate(FILE, 1):
    i += 1
    if (re.findall("*test1*", line)):
      # ... commands
      executed = True
      break # the break will exit the for loop
```

If that doesn't answer your question, please let me know in the comment. Because it seems to fit the description of your problem, and it works.

Comment: @scripter Does my answer fix your issue ? if yes i would appreciate if you validate my answer and/or vote it up, otherwise you can tell me the reason why it doesn't fix it.